# JavaScript - how to return a value and pass it

Tags: javascript, position

I am working on a function which will post some data - position of a flag/pin on the image trough api.

I am having a problem of passing position details.

```
function sendOnClick() {
    function get_posx() {
        var relx = $("#image_edit").click(function(e) {
            var relX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            return relX
        });
        return relx;
    }

    jQuery.post('{% url case_image_detail_api case.pk image.pk %}', {
        'id' : '{{image.id}}',
        'image_posx' : get_posx(),
        'image_posy' : get_posx(),
    });
};
```

Error:
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

Comment: You're binding a click event handler every time `sendOnClick` is called.

Comment: ...and the click() function doesn't return the result of the handler (remember it's asynchronous because fired by the user) but a jQuery object. Check where you jQuery.post() should be, inside the click function?

Comment: the get_posx() returns the $("#image_edit") object, not the relX

Comment: it would be good to store value of get_posx() in a variable before the jQuery.post call and then pass the variable to the jQuery.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above said, `sendOnClick` should be the event handler:

```
function sendOnClick(e) {
    var relX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var relY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    jQuery.post('{% url case_image_detail_api case.pk image.pk %}', {
        'id' : '{{image.id}}',
        'image_posx' : relX,
        'image_posy' : relY
    });
};

$("#image_edit").click(sendOnClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_posx` returns `relx`, which is a jQuery object (`$("#image_edit").click(…);`). This is not serializable to a HTTP argument as it contains DOM elements, and the XMLHTTPRequest complains about it.

If you want to send a request when the user clicks the image, you will need to put the `$.post` call inside the event handler!

```
$("#image_edit").click(function sendOnClick(e) {
    var relx = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        rely = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    jQuery.post('{% url case_image_detail_api case.pk image.pk %}', {
        'id' : '{{image.id}}',
        'image_posx' : relx,
        'image_posy' : rely
    });
});
```